# RequireJS: defining in callback

Tags: javascript, callback, requirejs, requirejs-define

In my module I want to defer the "define" call, but RequireJS running callback once file is loaded, not when "defined"... For example:

*a.js:*

```js
require(['b'], function(b){
  console.log(b);
});
```

*b.js:*

```js
define({'foo':'bar'});
```

This works as expected writing object {foo:bar}.
But if i move "define" to deferred function:

*b.js:*

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  define({'foo':'bar'});
}, 1000);
```

then console.log(b) writes "null".

What's wrong?

Comment: Well, you're delaying the define by 1 second and require is trying to request it before that timer has expired. Can I ask why you're delaying the define module?

Comment: It's just one of possible cases. Delay may be caused by ajax request or any other async process, needed for module to become ready.

Comment: It would make more sense to create a module that is responsible for your Ajax/async logic. That way you can just require it, and use the methods it provides to trigger any async stuff.

Comment: Hi Buncha, I tried delaying the call of define() too, because I wanted to simulate retrieving the the module over a slow internet connection.  Perhaps this isn't the way to do it?

Comment: Michael, I still have no solution for delaying define().
But i have advice for you: pack your module into server-side script and just use its sleep() function before sending module.

Answer (score 0):

I think that any delay or defer should happen inside the define function, or you could use some callback pattern like this:

```
//a.js
require(['b'], function(b){
  b.getData(
    function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
  );
});

//b.js
define(function(){
    this.getData = function(callback) {
        setTimeout(function(_callback){
            return function() {
                _callback({'foo':'bar'});
            }
        }(callback), 1000);     
    }
    return this;
});
```

Using this pattern you can set a callback function in a.js to handle the delayed answer from b.js.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks, I've done it like this already. But I tried to define in way, when the require-side knows nothing about delay...